# How to save a checkbox config_object in the schema files?

Tags: 8, entities, forms, hooks

We have a custom module with the following files. It is mainly used to store a list of content types that this configuration applies to. When saving the configuration, we get the following code.

How do we properly set the `mymodule.schema.yml` file to save the checkboxes?

Error Message. We also get the error message if we select `Basic Page` from the configuration.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.InvalidArgumentException:
>   The configuration property mymodule_enabled_content_types.article
>   doesn't exist. in Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\ArrayElement->get()
>   (line 76 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\ArrayElement.php).
>   Drupal\Core\Config\StorableConfigBase->castValue('mymodule_enabled_content_types.article
>   ', 'article ') (Line: 211)

**mymodule/config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml**

```
mymodule.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'My Module settings'
  mapping: 
    mymodule_enabled_content_types:
      type: string
      label: 'Enabled Content types'
```

**mymodule/config/install/mymodule.settings.yml**

```
mymodule_enabled_content_types: ''
```

**mymoduleForm.php**

```
...
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $config->$this->config('mymodule.settings');
  // Get all Content Types.
  $types = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node_type')
    ->loadMultiple();

  foreach($types as $type) {
    $content_types[$type->id()] = $type->label();
  }
  $form['mymodule_enabled_content_types'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => $this->t('Enabled Content Types'),
    '#description' => $this->t('Define what content types will be enabled.'),
    '#default_value' => $config->get('mymodule_custom_variable'),
    '#options' => $content_types,
  ];
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Retrieve the configuration
    $this->configFactory->getEditable('mymodule.settings')
      ->set('mymodule_enabled_content_types', $form_state->getValue('mymodule_enabled_content_types'))
      ->save();

    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating your checkbox options as an associative array of node type (bundle) IDs as keys and their labels as values.

When this form is submitted, checked checkboxes submit as `key => key`. So the stored information (I suppose 'rss_url' in your question is intended to being 'mymodule_enabled_content_types') is similar to:

```
mymodule_enabled_content_types:
  article: article
  page: page
  custom: custom
```

As the keys of the submitted values are unknown before submission, and the values clearly are strings, this is a **sequence** of strings (compare https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-schemametadata#properties). The correct schema definition is:

```
mymodule.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'My Module settings'
  mapping: 
    mymodule_enabled_content_types:
      type: sequence
      label: 'Enabled Content types'
      sequence:
        type: string
```

After changing your schema definition and rebuilding your caches, your form submit handler should work just fine and the configuration being saved using its correct data types.

Comment: yes that was a typo that i fixed, good catch. When i used the `sequence` as you mentioned it worked.